# Static pages to ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Ruby on rails, and in a month i will start a course on Ruby-on-Rails, but i would like to get some code going before i start the course since i want to learn as much as i can.

I made a project with:

```
rails new portfolio
```

Then i did:

```
rails generate controller portfolio index
```

To get the front page going.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'portfolio/index'


  resources :company

  root 'portfolio#index'
end
```

then:

```
rails generate controller company
```

controller:

```
class CompanyController < ApplicationController
    def new
    end
end
```

Then i made a file under views/portfolio/ called index.html.erb where my front page will be.
Under views/company/ i will have a file called company.

When i now go to the url: localhost:3000/company/company i get the error:

```
The action 'show' could not be found for CompanyController
```

My CompanyController is this:

```
    class CompanyController < ApplicationController
    def new
    end
end
```

Anyone that knows alot about ruby that can just give me a little pointer in the right direction?
Thanks.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Is there any actions called company inside the company controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with a single model and controller for companies. Create a `index` method inside the `app/controllers/companies_controller`. Then create the content inside file `app/views/companies/index.html.erb` to check that everything works, for example:

```
<h1> Hi! This is root page and index method in CompaniesController! </h1>
```

In `config/routes.rb`, you must specify a plural name for `companies` if you plan to create and process more than one, and leave it as it is, if the entity is the only one company for this project. Set plural name for this resource for this moment to create standard routes for CRUD:

```
resources :companies
root to: "companies#index"
```

More about routes you can find in [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).
You can try using the built-in [scaffold](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html) generator in order to quickly generate the application skeleton:

```
rails generate scaffold companies
```

The command above will generate controller, model, views and routes with CRUD methods in controller and views for the controller methods. Each view in `app/views/"resource_name_plural"` adjusted with method in controller in `config/routes.rb` file. This is how the MVC pattern works.

If you want to create static pages, maybe you should look at the [high_voltage gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage).

Answer (score 1):

In Rails you need to pay careful attention to pluralization. When declaring routes for a resource it should always be the plural form unless its the rare case where the resource really is singular (there can be only one).

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :companies
end
```

This will route to all companies at `/companies` and a single company at `/companies/:id`. If you thus try to get `/companies/company` it will be routed to the `#show` action since `/company` will be interpreted as the id.

Controllers should also be named in plural:

```
# app/controllers/companies_controller.rb
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_company, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /companies
  def index
    @companies = Company.all
  end

  # GET /companies/:id
  def show
  end

  # ...

  private
  def set_company
    @company = Company.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

You can use the scaffold command to get a full example of a standard rails CRUD controller:

```
rails g scaffold companies
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the create method, or new, you have to include the show method and index method.

in your routes

```
resources :companies
resources :portfolios
```

try in your controller:

```
class CompanyController < ApplicationController
    def new
    end
    def new 
    end
    def index
       @companies = Company.all 
    end
    def show 
    end
end
```

and if you have the controller you can create the views and point without problem

```
localhost:3000/company/company
```

This, I think it should be something more like this.

```
localhost:3000/companies/
```

always plural. 
Your controller will look for the view defined in the method. look how it is by default, that of a project of mine. in your place of groups will be companies.

[image]

look at the name of the views, are the same names of the methods of your controller. right?

Comment: `class CompanyController < ApplicationController
 def new
 end
 def show
 end
 def index
 end
end
`
This is what my controller looks like now, But now i get the error:

CompanyController#show is missing a template for this request format and variant.

Comment: Did you create the view?

Comment: create if it does not exist, a folder called companies, and inside create a new file called show.html.erb

Comment: as you generated the controller so, it by default did not generate the views, it only generates views when you generate scaffold

Comment: https://ibb.co/dXG4iH

This is my view. folder named company, and a file called company.html.erb that i want to list a company

Comment: I understand, but change this to index, so you'll get a list of companies

Comment: So, it worked??

Comment: My Index (front page) works fine and everything works just up to the point where i create the companies view and controller.

Comment: "If you have the create method, or new, you have to include the show method and index method." - this is very misleading. You don't.

Comment: I know, but somehow does he have to include it to show? it is not?

Comment: still giving the same error as before? even after you add the method and the view?

Comment: Yeah. I just started over, and changed the name from company (on the file, not the folder) to show, then i will work with that for now, just for training purposes.